# ToExpression an array

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a .dat file. I would like to convert a big array of strings(that's what I havein the .dat file) into an array of numbers, for example

```
a = {{"3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}, {"-3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"},{"3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}};
```

into

```
b = {{3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208}, {-3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208},{3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208}};
```

I tried to do

```
ToExpression[a]
```

but it does not work.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You will likely need to find a function to split strings.

Comment: Can you post the file contents instead?  It looks like the file was not imported correctly.  This conversion should be done at import time.  Try importing as `Import[..., "CSV"]`.  "dat" is not a standard file extension and Mathematica can't guess what's in the file, so you have to tell it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, "a" is a copy paste of the last three elements of the .dat file, I just added the left bracket "{" to give a toy small example with only three elements

Comment: @Mencia So are there any brackets in the file at all?  `a` is a Mathematica expression.  Can you copy and paste the file *literally*, with newlines preserved, etc.?

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you so much, Import[..., "CSV"] worked. Yes, the .dat file is a mathematica file, well at least it looks like it...

Comment: @Mencia If it's Mathematica syntax then it should be `Import[..., "Package"]`....

Comment: @Szabolcs, then it is not Mathematica sintax because Import[..., "Package"] does not work whereas Import[..., "CSV"] does work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of your file probably look like this:

```
str = 
" 3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208
 -3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208
  3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"
```

In the following I am going to use `ImportString` to be able to work with `str`, but the same applies to `Import` as well.

The values are separated by commas.  This format is called a CSV format---Comma Separated Values.

Make sure you always specify the format when using `Import` to read data.  In this case,

```
 ImportString[str, "CSV"]

 {{3, -3, 0, 5, 5, 0.000208}, {-3, -3, 0, 5, 5, 0.000208}, {3, -3, 0, 5, 5, 0.000208}}
```

You did not mention it in your question (please do next time!) but I think you may have wrote `ImportString[str, "Data"]` which will default to `ImportString[str, "Table"]` and results in

```
 {{"3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}, {"-3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}, {"3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}}
```

(Which is of course not a correct import of this data.)

Many people will try to use the import format `"Data"` (when the file has a `.dat` extension), and you'll find several examples of this online.  *This is based on a misunderstanding and it is incorrect.*  Do not do this.

There is no such import *format* as `"Data"` in Mathematica.  There is however an import *element*.  You'll find this in the documentation:

[image]

What happens when you write `ImportString[str, "Data"]` is that the *format* defaults to `"Table"` and the `"Data"` element is chosen.  There's another element for `"Table"`:

```
ImportString[str, {"Table", "Elements"}]

(* ==> {"Data", "Grid"} *)
```

You could have use `ImportString[str, "Grid"]` in the same way, which would also default to `"Table"` but choose the `"Grid"` element.

Instead of just specifying the element and letting the format be auto-detected, specify both: `ImportString["str, {"CSV", "Grid"}]`, or let only the element default to `"Data"` (which is what is needed most of the time).

---

**To sum up:**

1. Do specify the correct import format, which in this case is `"CSV"`
2. ".dat" is not a standard file extension and there no corresponding standard format
3. `"Data"` does not denote a format in Mathematica, but an import element. Do not use it without specifying a format if you need reliability.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{"3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}, {"-3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}, {"3,-3,0,5,5,0.000208"}};
Join @@ ToExpression@StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ a
```